# How can I consume an ActiveMQ message when data required is in MongoDB slave?

Tags: perl, mongodb, activemq-classic

This is more of a software architecture question.

Say I put some data in a MongoDB database and send an ActiveMQ message. The consumer of the message depends on the data being present in MongoDB, but if for scalability reasons the consumer uses a slave of the MongoDB database how can I be sure that the message will only be consumed when the data is in the replica?

I am using perl as my programming language, so I would prefer any potential solutions to be high level instead of, say, example java code.

Comment: Do you know when data reaches the replica?

Comment: Not yet as this is a hypothetical question. One would assume it us not certain due to latency or potential integrity issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there's no integration between ActiveMQ and MongoDB replication, you are limited to this:

1. Peek a message from the queue.
2. Verify that the data it needs is present on the slave.
3. If present, consume. Otherwise, proceed to next message.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Sergio's answer:

1. Take the message from the queue (pop)
2. Verify that the data it needs is present on the slave.
3. If present, consume. Otherwise, re-enqueue the message.